# Rehosting the WF4 designer - how to save and execute workflows created through the rehosted designer

Tags: serialization, workflow-foundation-4

I'm looking for some clarity with regards to the use of Windows Workflow 4 in an integrated solution - specifically with regards to rehosting the designer and executing workflows created by eg. a business user.

Is the intention that the required custom activities are created and compiled into a dll, which is then deployed with the rehosted designer, allowing the business user to create/configure workflows that make use of these activities - the business user would then save the workflow as XAML, which can be stored in a location known to the application (database, filesystem etc.), and then when it is necessary for the application to execute a workflow, it can use XamlServices.Load to load the workflow from the specific location and execute it as a DynamicActivity?

How is the workflow saved so that it can later be reserialized with properties and other configuration values? I've tried deserializing a Xaml file saved out of the designer, and also using XamlServices.save().

Are there any potential issues here with using bookmarks/persistence?

As a related question, is there any easy way to "Go back" in a workflow, without defining return branches on every flowchart element? I'm looking at integrating a workflow with a UI for a user to enter responses, which the wf will process, and make decisions based on the input. Through the UI, the user should be able to "Go Back" to a previous input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ActivityXamlServices.Load(path) to load a XAML file. It will return an Activity, actually a DynamicActivity, and you can use a WorkflowApplication to run it.

See [my blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx) for an exmple.

Comment: Thanks Maurice, I've followed your posts quite closely since WF4 Beta 1, and you provide a lot of useful insight & tips - particularly with the amount of "official" guidance being limited at this stage. Following your example I've actually got a working sample up and running now, and can edit in the rehosted designer, and run using a separate host. Would you say that it is recommended that Workflows live relatively standalone, and communicate with other areas of applications using messaging/WCF? (i.e. and not using InvokeMethod directly on another app assembly)? AppFabric seems to imply this.

Comment: Not sure if this is always the best approach, in fact I doubt it, but MS seems to be pushing us that way. Using the WorkflowServiceHost gives us most bang for the buck, specially when it comes to long running workflows. And from what I read about AppFabrik WCF is the way to go.
Now I think there certainly is a place for other communications/hosting stuff out there so don't dismiss the WorkflowApplication and bookmarks out of hand.

Comment: In my case my workflow.xaml resides in server and can access only via WCF service. Any samples available which rehosts workflow into workflow designer by reading from database or WCF?